# toolbar does not get populated

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

In my loadView methoad of my view controller I have the following code:

```
// Populate self.view and add some views/UI elements

// load Gender selection Bar
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.37 blue:0.5 alpha:1];

self.genderControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Male", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Female", nil), nil]];
genderControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
genderControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30);
genderControl.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.37 blue:0.5 alpha:1];
[genderControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeGender:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
genderControl.selectedSegmentIndex = GENDER_MALE;

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:genderControl];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

[[[self navigationController] toolbar] setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace, item, flexSpace, nil] animated:YES];
[item release];
```

However, if I load the view it displays the toolbar, but the Segmented Control does not get displayed. If I move my code to the viewWillAppear: method it works, but once I hide my view and redisplay it again the segmented control is gone anew.

Does anybody know this problem and/or has an idea how to solve it? Looks very strange to me.

Comment: One little quickie: you may have a memory leak in the line `self.genderControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSLocalizedString(@"Male", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Female", nil), nil]];` if the genderControl property is set to copy or retain you'd want to add an autorelease to the end of that all, otherwise you are incrementing the retain count by two rather than just one.

Comment: genderControl has a retain attribute but its released in the dealloc method, so the retain count is fine again. Thanks though!

Comment: But the line Simon is pointing end ups up having a retain count of 2 for genderControl (1 for self.= and 1 for alloc). Your dealloc will reduce that to 1, not 0 -- hence a memory leak! Simon's correct as far as I can see.

Comment: Am curious, what happens if you replace genderControl with a standard UIBarButtonItem of some sort? Same problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of your code looks fine to me, and everything should work when called from the `viewDidLoad` or the `loadView` method.

However, when you use the included toolbar from the NavigationController, toolbar items are set on the ViewController rather than the toolbar itself.  So replace this line:

```
[[[self navigationController] toolbar] setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace, item, flexSpace, nil] animated:YES];
```

With this:

```
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexSpace, item, flexSpace, nil] animated:YES];
```

Documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/setToolbarItems:animated:

You will also want to add this line:

```
[flexSpace release];
```

Comment: forgot the flexSpace release, thanks! Why would I want to ask my toolbar for sizeToFit though? I want it to span across the entire screen. Also, is there any reason why should I place the code in viewDidLoad rather than loadView if I create the viewController programmatically? I tried putting the code in viewDidLoad but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Robin sorry I didn't read your question carefully enough to see you were using the NavigationController.toolbar.  I have updated my answer to address this. When using this, there is no need for the sizeToFit. As for using the viewDidLoad vs the loadView, it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: Now I got it, didn't know about the ViewController toolbar items property. Actually thats a really smart system. Everything works fine now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this code should be in loadView? Check the [UIViewController docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1): loadView is used for constructing your view controller's view entirely programmatically - nothing is loaded from a nib if you implement loadView. Should this code be in viewDidLoad instead? I see that you're not even creating and assigning the main UIView in your loadView method -- which you'd normally expect to see, e.g.:

```
self.view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

If you *did* mean to implement loadView, as you have, you should add the above line for assigning your main view towards the top of the method, rather than later on.

Btw, perhaps don't bother calling [toolbar setItems] with animated=YES; not much point and I've seen the exact value of the animated parameter break things inexplicably in the past!

Comment: The view is created programmatically, nothing gets loaded from a nib as I'm not a big fan of Interface builder (so far). The view is set a few lines prior to the code posted, should have made that more clear.

Comment: Ah ok! It's perhaps wise to post the full method in future, as it avoids confusion!

Comment: Actually, can I suggest you edit your original post and put in the full code for your viewLoad? Other people may probably going to fall over the same non-problem I did, and it may help with someone answering the issue.

Comment: Sure you may, I edited the question to include a comment that the view gets initiated a couple of lines earlier. This should help :)